# why element is not added in dynamically in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to add data dynamically using `ng-repeat`. I don't know why it is not adding. I enter "name" which is added dynamically in the data, but it is not showing in the UI. Here is a [**demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/d40VjNXNzPGIYQWNrwzE?p=preview)

```
app.controller("studentcntr", ['$scope', function(scope) {
    scope.studentDetail = [];
    var student = {
        name: ''
    };

    scope.addStudent = function() {
        bootbox.prompt("Enter Name!", function(res){
            if (res == null) {

            } else {
                student.name = res;
                scope.studentDetail.push(student);
            }
        });
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bootbox is an external library, it is not aware that angularjs has digest cycles to keep the view up to date.

**[plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UMyQmELRv2PhLx1biL3d?p=preview)**

Just modify your code like this:

```
scope.addStudent=function(){
        bootbox.prompt("Enter Name!",function(res){
            if(res==null){

            }else {
                student.name=res;
                scope.studentDetail.push(student);
            }

            scope.$digest(); // here is the new line to update models
        });


    };
```

### OPTIONAL

To avoid you to come back later with another question you have to create an object each time for `student` inside your `bootbox`'s callback function scope to avoid pushing several times the same object in your `studentDetail` array.

As a result your final code could look like this:

```
app.controller("studentcntr",['$scope',function(scope){
    scope.studentDetail=[];

    // I removed var student

    scope.addStudent=function(){
        bootbox.prompt("Enter Name!",function(res){
            if (res == null) {

            } else {
                scope.studentDetail.push({ name: res });
            }

            scope.$digest(); // here is the new line to update models
        });

    };
}]);
```

Comment: can you share plunker..!! downvoter please comment

Comment: I can share the plunker for sure. I did not downvote your question btw.

Comment: your answer is wrong ...I apply your concept it make one row, if I added again it update that row , not generate second row

Comment: @user3703527 I shared plunkr, and by the way if you read my answer *entirely* you'd know that I answered that part in my optional section.

Comment: thanks it is working ....last can we give id option to each row like that "name_1","name_2"

Comment: in your ng-repeat td, just add this `id="name_{{$index}}"` it will give name_0, name_1 etc. if you want to start from 1 just add `1` to `$index`

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
scope.studentDetail.push(student);
```

is executed outside of angular, so angular doesn't know that studentDetail is already changed. You can use scope.$apply() to ask angular to check for changes

```
scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.studentDetail.push({
        name: res
    });
});
```

Another issue with your code is that you declare a variable student inside the controller. So every time you push it inside scope.studentDetail, you are actually pushing the same object again, which will cause error in ng-repeat. I changed in the above code to push new object every time

Comment: it is also good solution